# TSQL - How to bulk insert with " encapsulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm updating a functional Bulk Insert for a tab-delimited file with double quotes.  That statement is then wrapped inside an Execute() so I can add a few variables later.

The following code works fine except it doesn't remove the " from each field:

```
EXECUTE('
  BULK INSERT MySQLtable 
  FROM "\\mynetworkdrive\a' + @somedate + '.txt" with (Firstrow=2)
')
```

How do I update this so that it removes the double quotes on import?

I'm looking for something like:

```
EXECUTE('
  BULK INSERT MySQLtable 
  FROM "\\mynetworkdrive\a' + @somedate + '.txt" with (Firstrow=2, fieldterminator='"   "')
')
```

The only advice I can find suggest creating a fmt file or using `Update` statements for each field after it's imported (my current method). Is this even possible to do this with just the Bulk Insert?

Comment: Have you tried `fieldterminator='"\t"'`. I'd probably stick to the updates though.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work inside the Execute statement.